# How to select rows filtered with condition on the previous and the next rows in pandas and put them in a empty df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Considering the following dataframe `df` :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        "col2": ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"],
        "col3": [1e-0,1e-1,1e-2,1e-3,1e-4,1e-5,1e-6,1e-7,1e-8,1e-9,1e-10],
        "col4": [0,4,2,5,6,7,6,3,6,2,1]
    }
)
```

I would like to select rows when the *col4* value of the current row is greater than the *col4* values of the previous and next rows and to store them in an empty frame.

I wrote the following code that works :

```
df1=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1,len(df)-1,1):
    if ( (df.iloc[i]['col4'] > df.iloc[i+1]['col4']) and (df.iloc[i]['col4'] > df.iloc[i-1]['col4']) ):
        df1=pd.concat([df1,df.iloc[i:i+1]])
```

I got the expected dataframe `df1`

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
1   1   B   1.000000e-01    4
5   5   F   1.000000e-05    7
8   8   I   1.000000e-08    6
```

But this code is very ugly, not readable, ... Is there a best solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with compare next and previous values by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for greater values, for chain bitwise `AND` use `&`:

```
df = df[df['col4'].gt(df['col4'].shift()) & df['col4'].gt(df['col4'].shift(-1))]
print (df)
   col1 col2          col3  col4
1     1    B  1.000000e-01     4
5     5    F  1.000000e-05     7
8     8    I  1.000000e-08     6
```

EDIT: Solution for always include first and last rows:

```
mask = df['col4'].gt(df['col4'].shift()) & df['col4'].gt(df['col4'].shift(-1))
mask.iloc[[0, -1]] = True
df = df[mask]
print (df)
    col1 col2          col3  col4
0      0    A  1.000000e+00     0
1      1    B  1.000000e-01     4
5      5    F  1.000000e-05     7
8      8    I  1.000000e-08     6
10    10    K  1.000000e-10     1
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is better. Just a precision, for the first and last rows, I could do comparison only with one row because the other does not exist. What is going on when `shift` is used on rows that does not exist ?

Comment: @Stef1611 - It compare with `NaN`s, so always False - practically it means always excluded first anad lasr rows.

Comment: I read the `gt` doc. Do you think is it used a good idea to set `fill_value` to negative infinity ?

Comment: @Stef1611 - Do you need some solution for include first or last rows? Or what is reason for replace to negative infinity?

Comment: Exact. If I may, I need a solution to include the first and last rows without adding code lines for the first and last rows if possible.

Comment: @Stef1611 - I think simpliest is manually set `True` in mask, added to solution.

Comment: I am not sure I was clear. For the first and last rows, tests must be done but only with the row that exists. For example, for the first row, one test is only done (with the value of the second row) because the previous row does not exist. So this row should not be selected because 4 > 0. That is why I imagined to replace Nan with -inf because everything is greater than -inf.

Comment: @Stef1611 - Yop, agree, it is good solution - `df[df['col4'].gt(df['col4'].shift(fill_value=-np.inf)) & df['col4'].gt(df['col4'].shift(-1,fill_value=-np.inf))]`

Comment: Anyway, thanks for this enriching exchange and to inform me about pandas series.